# Should I stick to AM3+ or upgrade to something else?

Tags: processor, motherboard

My motherboard just died on me, and I am wondering if I should just stick to the same kind of motherboard (AM3+). If i do I would be able to reuse the cpu, ram, and psu for a bit longer. Is it even worth it to keep using the CPU and RAM, or should I just upgrade to another kind of motherboard and get a newer CPU? Is AM3+ obsolete at this point? If I should upgrade, what should I upgrade to for the motherboard and CPU?

I mainly use the computer for gaming (at medium to high settings) and a bit for light programming work.

My Current specs are:
CPU:          AMD FX-6300 6 core -
Motherboard:  AsusTek M5A78l-M/USB3 - AM3+ -
GPU:          NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3gb - 
OS:           Windows - 
RAM:          DDR3 - 
SSD:          Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500 GB - 
PSU:          EVGA 600W - 
OS:           Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in its CPU benchmark score, this CPU gives middle-of-the-road performance, but it is 6 years old.  That said, performance increases over time have slowed a lot.

If your system is able to fo everything you need  it to and your usage case is unlikely to change in the next 12 months or more, and the motherboard is less then $100, it's financially reasonable to replace the motherboard and defer a new purchase.

Comment: Where did you find its CPU Benchmark score?

Comment: @alex https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+FX-6300+Six-Core

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an AM3+ mobo considering that it's pretty cheap, I've seen your mobo at ~50€ in France. Of course it depends on your country.

Changing mobo + CPU + ram is expensive nowadays, if your CPU is still enough for you, keep it a bit more.